# Creating a Tabular table based on a query and not a physical table in SSDT

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-data-tools, azure-analysis-services

I've created a tabular model in Power BI and now I'd like to create that same model in Azure Analysis Services, using Visual Studio 2017 and SSDT. Some of my tables in my Power BI model have a SQL query as the source and not a physical table or view. However, in SSDT, when I attempt to add a new table to my model I'm not given the choice of entering a SQL query. It seems I have to either select a physical table or a view.

In SSDT is it not possible to add a table to my model based on a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top menu bar, go to **Model** then **Existing Connections**. After this press **Open** and select the second radio button, "Write a query that will specify the data to import."  If you're accessing an object that's not in the database used as the Initial Catalog in the connection string then the three part naming convention (Database.Schema.Table) is necessary.

Comment: Thank you but when I click on the Model menu option, I don't see an Existing Connections option. I see Import From Data Source..., Add Data Source... Analyze in Excel, Process etc.

Comment: There should be an Existing Connections option below there.  If you right click the data source in the Data Sources folder in the Tabular Model Explorer window, you can select the "Import New Tables" option, which will have the "Write a query..." choice on the initial page.  To see the Tabular Model Explorer, go to View > Other Windows > Tabular Model Explorer.

Comment: Hmm... It's almost as if you and I are not using the same version of SSDT. When I right-click on Import New Tables, I see a list of tables from which to choose but no option to "Write a query". BTW, I'm using the latest version of SSDT (15.8).

Comment: I just read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/ssas-import-query?view=sql-server-2017. It may be this feature has been removed in favor of using expressions instead.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I was wondering that too.  I'm guessing you're able to use a query via the Expressions option from the link you referenced?